# SQL: How to SUM and AVG on a left/right JOIN

Tags: sql, ruby, database

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdZPz.png)

With the table above, I basically I want to be able to return an array of

```
[average minutes, genre, number of movies of that genre]
```

like

```
[[86, "Horror", 34]......[66, "Comedy", 32]]
```

So far I have coded like this but it doesn't work

```
SELECT AVG(movies.minutes), genres.name, COUNT(movies.name)
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN genres
ON genres.id = movies.genre_id
```

It returns the average of all movies, a single genre and all the movies like

```
[82, "Horror, 223]
```

Comment: You should please provide some sample input data and corresponding outcome. You will very likely need to add a GROUP BY clause to your query.

Comment: just add "GROUP BY genres.name" to the bottom of ur query

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aggregation functions without grouping them.
Try adding a [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause in your statement.

Comment: If he/she couldn't, it would appear an error message, but as you see, the query was successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the `GROUP BY genres.name` at the end of your query. Therefore, your query should be

```
SELECT AVG(movies.minutes), genres.name, COUNT(movies.name)
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN genres
   ON genres.id = movies.genre_id
GROUP BY genres.name
```

You may ask why your query without `GROUP BY genres.name` works and returns 'horror'. The answer is that 'horror' returned by the query is picked by random and tomorrow you may get 'comedy'.